# How to customize json wrapped key for class during deserialization if I am not able to mark that class with annotation?

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, wrapper

I have model class like this:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.*;

public class MyPojo {
    int id;
    public int getId()
    { return this.id; }

    public void setId(int id)
    { this.id = id; }


}
```

And json json has format like this:

```
{ 
    "root":{  
       "MyPojo":{  
          "id":4
       }
    }
}
```

I read about solution via annotations `@JsonTypeInfo` or `@JsonRoot` but I am not able to apply this because I take this class from library.

Also I read about solution like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
```

But I can't use it because:
1. It is setting for all classes but I need to change behaviour only for 1 class right now
2. It will check that root key corresponds the class name(`mypojo` in my case) but I it is not true for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The way to go here is adding a custom deserializer. There you can manipulate json programatically to create your `MyPojo` instance

```
public class MyPojoDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<MyPojo> {

    @Override
    public Item deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        return new MyPojo(node.get("root").get("MyPojo").get("id").numberValue());
    }
}
```

then register deserializer

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(MyPojo.class, new MyPojoDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```